# Truncating contents of Android TextView to fit width

Tags: android

how can i find the number of character fit into the textview of android.
if suppose textview can fit only 25 character so i can get the substring from 0,25 and assign to textview. 
so is it possible ?
thanx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TextViews natively support automatically clipping their contents using the [`ellipsize`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize) property; setting the `maxLines` (or `singleLine`) on the TextView and adding `android:ellipsize="end"` will probably get the effect you're looking for without you having to muck about with substring operations yourself.